# Rails collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make use of the `collection_check_boxes` method.

A `group`has many `users`and a user can belong to multiple `groups`.

`user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end
```

`group.rb`

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

`groupes.controller.rb`

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController

 def new
    @group = Group.new
 end
end
```

`new.html.slim`

```
h1 Groupes

.hsep

.container-fluid

 == form_for @group, { html: { class: 'form-horizontal', remote:true, id: 'new_user' } } do |f|

.form-group
    .col-sm-10
        == f.collection_check_boxes :group, :user_ids, User.all, :id, :login

== f.submit
```

My goal is that when a new `group`is created, the user can choose which `users`belong to that group with a checkbox list from all the users.

The error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `merge' for :login:Symbol):
13: 
14:     .form-group
15:         .col-sm-10
16:             == f.collection_check_boxes :group, :user_ids, User.all, :id, :login
17: 
18:     == f.submit
```

I most likely missed something on how to properly use `collection_check_boxes`but I just can't get around fixing it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you didn't pass "text_method" argument to `collection_check_boxes`

If you have user's column `name` when add it and remove `:group` because you use it with `form_for`

```
== f.collection_check_boxes :user_ids, User.all, :id, :name
```

Comment: Indeed, updated original post but still not working.

Comment: Remove `:group`

Comment: This did the trick, plus generating the migration with the correct association table name.